# How to shrink "permanent" tablespace?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I have a tablespace has size 307,200 MB and "Used (MB)" is 103 229,81. This tablespace was created with "BIG" Datafile. For recent time "Used (MB)" value increase insignificantly. So I want to shrink the tablespace.

```
alter tablespace MYTABLESPACE shrink space keep 130G
```

raises

> ORA-12916: cannot shrink permanent or dictionary managed tablespace

Yes. This tablespace is "permanent", but its size is bigger in three times than the used size is, and this fact is a problem for me. How can I shrink it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is quite straightforward. You are trying to shrink a permanent tablespace using a command to shrink temporary tablespace.

> ```
> 12916, 00000, "cannot shrink permanent or dictionary managed tablespace"
> // *Cause: An attempt was made to shrink a permanent tablespace or a
> //         dictionary managed tablespace.
> // *Action: Check the tablespace type and issue the statement only on
> //          locally managed temporary tablespaces.
> ```

Example to resize BIGFILE Tablespace.

```
ALTER TABLESPACE bigtbs RESIZE 80G;
```

Refer to [Altering and Maintaining Tablespaces](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17120/tspaces007.htm)

Comment: Thank you. Unfotunately, I was able to shrink only to 205G by an unсlear reason.

Comment: Your "unclear" reason is only "unclear" because you failed to post the very clear error message.  Most likely it failed because the high-water mark was at 205 G.   To resize a file, it is not just a matter of how much unused space it has, but WHERE that unused space is located.